# ¿Cómo puedo explicar el significado de "pareces agobiado/a"?

Tags: significado, definiciones

Estaba pensando en cómo explicar a una persona extranjera el significado de la frase "pareces agobiado/a" y no se me acaba de ocurrir la mejor manera de hacerlo.

Según el [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/agobiar#169H9KA), las acepciones de "agobiar" a las que me refiero son

> 1. tr. Imponer a alguien actividad o esfuerzo excesivos, preocupar gravemente, causar gran sufrimiento. *La agobian los quehaceres, los años, las penas*.
> 2. tr. Rendir, deprimir o abatir.

Entonces se me ocurre "tu manera de comportarte da la sensación de que hay algo que te tiene muy preocupado". Pero no me convence: hay matices del significado de "agobiado" que se pierden en esta explicación.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a encontrar una definición mejor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que en "pareces agobiado", el participio/adjetivo tiene, a diferencia de otros participios (ej. aburrido, sorprendido), un fuerte significado pasivo: *pareces agobiado por algo*.

Podrías explicar a tus alumnos que:

- Pareces agobiado.

es una paráfrasis de:

- Parece que algo te agobia.

Si bien podemos decir "parece que algo te aburre" o "parece que algo te sorprende/te ha sorprendido" para explicar el significado de "aburrido" o "sorprendido" en estructuras copulativas similares, en el caso de "agobiado" el agente que causa el agobio parece tener más peso que el agente que causa el aburrimiento o la sorpresa.

Comment: De acuerdo, Gustavson, lo que pasa es que se trata de personas que no entienden el significado de "agobiar". Y me da la sensación que con tu explicación + la definición de la RAE se pierde algún matiz. Pero quizás esté bien así.

Comment: "agobiar" es causar pesadumbre, un cansancio insoportable, una preocupación angustiante...

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias.